# Get Data from firebase. Display only the thata that maches the currentdate

Tags: firebase

So i'm making an app and I want display birthdays that i have inputed in firebase. The problem is that i don't know how to get only that data that matches currentdata.

Comment: What platform are you using? JavaScript?

Comment: Yes I am using javascript

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your collection is called `users` and the birthday field is called `birthday`, and it is a `timestamp` type field. What you can do is use two `where` clauses in your query to find any timestamp value between two dates:

```js
db.collection('users').where('birthday', '>=', new Date(2022, 2, 4)).where('date', '<', new Date(2022, 2, 5));
```

This will select any `user` that has a birthday today (**while also considering the year and time**). However, this probably is not what you want. If someone was born on March 4th, 2000, I'm assuming you would also want this record to be returned, due to the nature of birthdays.

In this case, what you should do is add two `number` fields to your `user` records in lieu of the single `birthday` timestamp field. Add a `birthdayMonth` field and a `birthdayDay` field. Then, you can query any `user` with a birthday today (irrespective of the year) by looking at those two values:

```js
const now = new Date();
db.collection('users').where('birthdayMonth', '==', now.getMonth()).where('birthdayDay', '==', now.getDay());
```